# Visual Studio Code Custom Extension Line Based Note

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to create an extension for visual studio code, which requires the ability to annotate lines in a file similar to the references shown in the image, linked below.

[image: Example]

I want to be able to add an annotation, such as the one shown in the red rectangle, without modifying the source code file. I would like to be able to do so for every line of the source file. I also want to be able to make dynamic modifications to the annotations' contents.

I have searched VSC's documentation as well as elsewhere. I have not found it. Can anyone guide me in the right direction please?

I know the following is incorrect, but I don't know where else to check for how it should be accomplished.

```
class TestCodeLensProvider implements vscode.CodeLensProvider {
    public provideCodeLenses(document: TextDocument, token: CancellationToken):
        CodeLens[] | Thenable<CodeLens[]> {
        return new Array<CodeLens>();
    }

    public resolveCodeLens?(codeLens: CodeLens, token: CancellationToken):
        CodeLens | Thenable<CodeLens> {
        return new CodeLens(new vscode.Range(new vscode.Position(1, 1), new vscode.Position(1, 2)),/*I also don't know how to specify my command here*/ );
    }
}

export function activate(ctx: vscode.ExtensionContext): void {
    ctx.subscriptions.push(
        vscode.languages.registerCodeLensProvider(
            'json', new TestCodeLensProvider()));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature in your screenshot is called "Code Lens". More specifcally, you're looking for the `registerCodeLensProvider()` function of the [`languages` namespace](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#_languages). Or if you're writing a Language Server instead of using the VSCode API directly, [the `textDocument/codeLens` request method](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/specification#textDocument_codeLens).

Comment: Sorry for the long delay in response time. I wanted to be sure I tried all I could think of before asking another question. I a having problems figuring out what exactly I need to do to complete the functions provideCodeLenses and resolveCodeLenses. Am I supposed to supply an array of codeLens to the first and a single codeLens to the second? I am really lost on this one.

Comment: Perhaps looking at an implementation example, such as in the build-in TypeScript extension helps? https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/86feb84737e13aab68d19305c8a0beecc92d45a0/extensions/typescript-language-features/src/features/referencesCodeLensProvider.ts Note that `resolveCodeLens()` is optional / doesn't _have_ to be implemented.